# Setting up "Tarpit" technique in iptables

Tags: iptables

I have a new server running CentOS 5.3 with iptables v1.3.5. I'm not familiar with iptables and trying to setting up the "Tarpit" technique in iptables, but so far this is what I got:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s x.x.x.x -p tcp -j TARPIT
```

I really have no idea about the command. Do I need to modify some part of the command?

Answer (score 2):

the `TARPIT` target is part of xtables_addons and only usable for TCP connections; providing your system actually has the xtables_addons targets, you can use this target as a way of "harassing" any would-be attackers since sending them to the `TARPIT` will cause their scanning script to think that the TCP session is alive; simply using `DROP` can be avoided by the attacker simply by using a short connection timeout.

So, if you're running any iptables rules for tcp connections that you would normally `DROP` - consider `TARPIT` instead; additionally, if you are also using connection tracking but unconditionally `TARPIT`-ing a port, add a `NOTRACK` rule to your `raw` table for that port to avoid consuming conntrack resources.

Comment: do have any good references about adding `NOTRACK` and `raw` table?

Comment: both can be compiled into the kernel, or as modules, beyond that, I don't know what it is you're asking.

Comment: @Olipro: do you have an idea as to whether similar behavior (i.e. sending `ACK` and then not doing anything) can be achieved some other way with the vanilla modules usable in `iptables`?